# Why do I get a null reference exception when my source class has a property called "Original" and my destination is a record?

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I have the following minimal C# code.

Notice that my source class `From` has a nullable property called `Original`. My destination `To` is a **record**.

When I run this code, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

- If the property is called anything other than **Original**, the code works.
- If the destination is a class instead of a record, the code works

Why does it only throw when the property is called Original and the destination is a record?

```
using AutoMapper;

var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(conf =>
{
    conf.CreateMap<From, To>();
}).CreateMapper();

var from = new From();
var to = mapper.Map<To>(from);

public class From
{
    public string? Original { get; set; }

    public bool BoolProp { get; set; }
}

public record To
{
    public bool BoolProp { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: Possibly a bug. Have you reported it?

Comment: Naa, the Github repository told me to post to StackOverflow in case I'm a dummy. I'll report it to the repo next though if there is no other explanation 

Comment: Out of interest, I took most of the code that a record generates (via sharplab.io) and created a relatively similar type for that in a fiddle and I also get the same issue. It seems that AutoMapper is somehow favouring the constructor that takes an existing instance and copies it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DP7Shu

Comment: It seems that the issue can be solved by changing the mapping to `conf.CreateMap<From, To>().ConstructUsing(_ => new To());`, though this does point to a bug IMHO.

Comment: The _bigger_ question is _how you came up with this scenario_ that highlighted the issue? ;)

Comment: What does `AssertConfigurationIsValid` say?

Comment: Ohhh! It's because the constructor parameter in the _record_ is `original` and your string is `Original`. AutoMapper is trying to be smart.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with C# 10 `readonly record struct`?

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this in the future, I raised this as an [issue on the AutoMapper Github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4057), but the issue was closed and discussion removed, so I don't think this is going to be fixed.

Comment: @RowanFreeman What a bummer, did the discussion have any input from the maintainers before they removed and closed it?

Comment: Sadly no. They closed it with no responses, so I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my own investigation, it seems that the autogenerated class for the `To` record actually has two constructors. One takes an existing `To` and the other is parameterless. [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMYHsEBNXIwJwYzIA0uIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUPQMwAETPAYR4BvDj3F9emHLh4AVLGImj2EtZJ7AsWADY8AQtp0AFBFgAOIngHMIMANw8AlgDsnDngF8l47+09AA):

```cs
protected To(To original)
{
    <BoolProp>k__BackingField = original.<BoolProp>k__BackingField;
}

public To()
{
}
```

A call to `mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` states:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The following member on To cannot be mapped:
> To.Void .ctor(To).parameter original

It seems that the constructor parameter of `To` being named `original` and your property being named as `original` is causing AutoMapper to choose an incompatible constructor from the record.

It seems that this is probably an edge case bug that you've discovered. You should probably report this to the maintainers via GitHub.

As for a workaround, you could change your property name away from `Original` or explicitly tell AutoMapper how to construct a `To`: `conf.CreateMap<From, To>().ConstructUsing(_ => new To());`.

Either approach solves the problem and satisfies `mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`.

Comment: This bug would manifest in any instance where one of the properties matches a constructor parameter by name but not type

Comment: @Charlieface Indeed it would. Though I would hope the "copy" constructor on the record would be a special case for AutoMapper. On the other hand, Microsoft seem to want to make them effectively indistinguishable from regular classes, so it seems a little difficult to detect whether a  type is a class. It would be nice if AM threw up an exception to point out the type mismatch rather than just ending up passing `null`.